# Time Complexity of .equals() vs .equalsignorecase() vs .contains()

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, web-crawler, breadth-first-search

I am tasked with creating a BFS Web crawler without using imported libraries such as LinkedList and ArrayList.

As such, I need to create my own implementation of Dynamic Arrays and LinkedList.

One of the requirements is to try to make my program more efficient than if I were to just use the imported libraries.

When checking if the URL I have crawled for is already in my Dynamic Array I am using equals() or equalsignorecase() instead of contains()

May I ask if this will improve the time complexity?

I understand that worst case they are O(n) but I see that equals() can sometimes be O(1)

```
`
        public boolean find (String URL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.arraylist.length; i++) {
            if (URL.equalsIgnoreCase(this.arraylist[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
`
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code which explains us what exactly is `nameofda`?

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing that out, i have since edited my question. Nameofda stands for name of dyanmic array, which is my own implementation of dynamic array

Comment: And is arraylist an array of Strings?

Comment: Yes arraylist is an array of Strings

Comment: "I see that equals() can sometimes be O(1)" it is optimized to check for object identity first, and to check for unequal string length before doing the character-wise comparison.

Comment: Note: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are not libraries, just classes included in standard Java (`java.base` module); the same as `String` itself (and I believe/hope you are allowed to use `String`) || `contains()` is much probably using `equals()`, so it is not very useful to compare both

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back to me, I am really new to this so pls forgive me if i sound uninformed. Basically I am not allowed to use any imports

Answer (score -2):

Do you not have 'Hashmap' or even 'Vector' ?

Seems to me you're doing a sequential search of an array, which is O(n), not so good.

Instead, you could have an an array of arraylists, and make use of the hashcode. Something like:

```
List<String>[] arrayLists = new List[100];
{
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) arrayLists[i] = new ArrayList();
}

 public void store(String URL){
    arrayLists[URL.hashCode()%arrayLists.length].add(URL);
 }

 public boolean find (String URL) {
        List<String> myArrayList = arrayLists[URL.toLowerCase().hashCode()%arrayLists.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (URL.equalsIgnoreCase(myArrayList.get(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
 }
```

This should give you a complexity of O(N/arrayLists.length) - As the length of arrayLists approach the length of your number of URL's, complexity would fall to O(1) worse case.

Comment: 1) You are using the case sensitive hashcode for a case insensitive lookup. This doesn’t work at all. 2) The result of `%` can be negative. It’s not sufficient for mapping to a 0..length range. 3) You are creating a zero length array but try to assign it to a type `List[100]`, which isn’t even valid Java syntax. 4) You have an array of `List` but try to get an `ArrayList` without a cast. 5) You are confusing the local variable `myArrayList` with a field access `this.myArrayList` 6) You try to access the `ArrayList` as if it was an array.

Comment: It was a concept, which I wrote without IDE's, compilers or testing.

I am not here to do write your code for you,

Comment: Well, I spotted the errors as well “without IDE's, compilers or testing”. It took me again just one second to spot that you are still using `hashCode()` at one place, which isn’t compatible with the use of `.toLowerCase().hashCode()` at the other place. Not to speak of the fact that the hash code of the lowercase string still isn’t compatible with `equalsIgnoreCase` for certain Unicode characters. Further, you’re still ignoring the fact that hash codes can be negative, so `%` doesn’t safely map to an array location. It might be helpful to *you* in the future, to become aware of such things.